# How to use Printout3D with colors?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, 3d-printing

I would like to 3D print some full-color 3d graphics. Obvious attempts fail:

```
Printout3D @ Region[Style[DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}]], Green]]
```

However, `Printout3D` supports three services: IMaterialise, Shapeways, and Sculpteo, all of which support color. For example, in [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/product/SCMCP5WH9/twisted-earth?optionId=41231187&li=curatedproductGroup):

[image]

They support uploading your [object in the X3D format](https://support.shapeways.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023735054-Exporting-to-VRML-and-X3D-for-color-printing), a format that is also supported in wolfram.

So is there any workaround to color 3D printing (with any amount of color information - vertex color data, textures, lighting, etc.) using with the `Printout3D` workflow in any service?

Comment: Assuming FFF printing... Color prints are usually achieved by combining different models, one for each color. The group of models is expected to fit together to form the whole shape to be printed. The slicer will generate the appropriate gcode to perform the filament switch and the waste tower at each layer. So, in Mathematica, I assume you'd need to generate the graphics or region for each color and export each to stl and combine them in your slicer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is too open-ended, isn't directly related to WL code, isn't directly related to Mathematica usage patterns, and can't really be answered without knowledge of the full 3D printing workflow of the OP.

Comment: This question is very clear and directed related to WL code - we are talking about the fundamental 3D printing workflow of Mathematica - which has a dedicated symbol no less.

Comment: So, an acceptable answer for you is "use Printout3D"?

Comment: No because that will fail to preserve colors, we need an example workflow of printing where the colors of the vertices in the mesh are produced, it should be possible since some printers support this, but there are no examples of printing surface colors in the docs.

Comment: As I said, the usual way to do multi-color printing is to have a separate model for each color. That twisted Earth example looks more complicated that what I'm familiar with in 3d printing in terms of the color, so I don't know exactly what's going on there. But your question was how to print in color. The way to do that is to separate the thing you want to print into a specific model for each color.

Comment: So, if you're printing a smiley face with yellow backgroung and black eyes, you'd create a model for the yellow and a model for the black. This might be done by starting with a disk and then creating a "cutout" for the eyes. The cutout itself would be one model, and then the disk-minus-cutout would be the rest of the face. You'd produce an stl for the yellow face and an stl for the black eyes. In your slicer, you'd import each stl and assign a filament for each. Your slicer will create the gcode, which will include swapping the filaments and creating a waste tower.

Comment: So, you'd just use Printout3D twice.

Comment: Now, I'm only familiar with printers like Prusa's filament printers (i.e. not their SLA printers). So, if you know of some other way to print multiple colors, then that's great. But that's also sort of the point of closing this question. It's not specific enough. If you could provide your printing workflow, your target printer, and all the various other details that determine what output you need from Mathematica, then maybe I could help you figure it out. Absent that, this question isn't actionable.

Comment: Okay, I did some quick research. That twisted Earth model is printed with zp150 powder (cf [catalog](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Talks/Simons/illustrating_geometry_catalog.pdf)). I think you need an industrial quality printer for that (we're talking in the 10s of thousands of dollars range). I suspect that you'd need a special slicer as well.

Comment: Given the detail and color blending, it cannot use the method that I'm familiar with. Slicers that I found that target printers that use that powder do seem to accept stl as input. So, either there exists some special stl format that specifies color as well as geometry, or the color is specified some other way (probably, again, within a special slicer). At this point I'm fairly certain that this is beyond what Mathematica supports.

Comment: @lericr I edited the question to make it easier to answer, hopefully this helps!